# AWS lightsail: Could not connect to the endpoint URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud, amazon-lightsail

I am trying to use AWS lightsail to deploy a Flask application.

I was following this tutorial: https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/serve-a-flask-app/.

So far, I have created an AWS account, created an Administrator user with permissions, generated the access key pair, installed the aws CLI, configured the CLI with `aws configure`, and installed lightsailctl.

I created a container with Docker, and now I am on the step where we are supposed to use this command to create a lightsail container service:

```
> aws lightsail create-container-service --service-name flask-service --power small --scale 1
```

but I am getting this output error below.

```
Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://lightsail.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/"
```

I was wondering if there is anything visibly wrong here; I feel like I've followed the tutorial fine. Let me know if you want more information too.

Also, I've only just created my AWS account a couple of hours ago, so that might be the issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Amazon Lightsail service **is not available in the `us-west-1` region**:

[image: Amazon Lightsail regions]

Perhaps you intended to use `us-east-1` or `us-west-2`? Or, perhaps you have `us-west-1` set as your default region in your AWS config files? If so, you'll need to override it by specifying a different region when using the AWS CLI.

Comment: This worked, thanks! I did have us-west-1 as default in my config files. I fixed it by just running the `aws config` command again, and rewriting the region as us-west-2. Hope this helps others.

Comment: What is the amount of storage offered by the lightsail container service? The pricing page only shows cpu and memory. I have a python api running on lightsail container service. It's POST endpoint receives a file, stores it in temporary folder, processes the file, deletes the file and responds back with processed JSON. I am curious to know what is the disk space capacity of the lightsail container service.